# How can I produce 'tombstone compaction' in cassandra 1.2.6

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

Regarding [tombstone compaction](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tombstone-removal-improvement-in-1-2)

I'd like to know why I can't produce 'tombstone compaction' in cassandra1.2.6.

[steps]

1. create column family in cassandra-cli

   `create keyspace keyspace1 
   with placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' 
   and strategy_options = {replication_factor:3};`

   `use keyspace1;`

   `create column family cf1 
   with comparator=AsciiType 
   and default_validation_class=AsciiType 
   and key_validation_class=AsciiType 
   and compaction_strategy_options={tombstone_compaction_interval: 1, tombstone_threshold: '0.1'}
   and gc_grace=600
   and column_metadata=[ 
     {column_name: column1, validation_class: LongType} 
   ];`
2. Entry some data with TTL in cassandra-cli as following

   `set cf1['key1']['column1']=100 with ttl = 1;

   set cf1['key2']['column1']=200 with ttl = 1;

   set cf1['key3']['column1']=300 with ttl = 1;

   set cf1['key4']['column1']=400 with ttl = 600;

   set cf1['key5']['column1']=500 with ttl = 600;

   set cf1['key6']['column1']=600 with ttl = 600;`
3. execute 'nodetool flush'
4. check Data.db with sstable2json

   `{"key": "2412441","columns": [["column1","100",1373516242953000,"d"]]},

   {"key": "2412442","columns": [["column1","200",1373516242963000,"d"]]},

   {"key": "2412443","columns": [["column1","300",1373516242973000,"d"]]},

   {"key": "2412444","columns": [["column1","400",1373516242983000,"e",600,1373516300]]},

   {"key": "2412445","columns": [["column1","500",1373516242983000,"e",600,1373516300]]},

   {"key": "2412446","columns": [["column1","600",1373516242983000,"e",600,1373516300]]}`
5. Wait over 1hour.... It has no change in Data.db.... tombstone compaction wasn't produced...
6. Entry some data and execute nodetool flush again... Just new Data.db was created... tombstone compaction wasn't produced...

I'd like to just try 'tombstone compaction'.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have enough data in the sstable for Cassandra to guess the tombstone ratio.  You can use the getDroppableTombstoneRatio method from ColumnFamilyStoreMBean over JMX to check.

Comment: I tried to use some GB data. But tombstone compaction was not produced...
The DroppableTombstoneRatio is 0.5336280444019503.
What is the trigger of tombstone compaction?

Comment: tombstone_threshold is a compaction strategy option that defaults to 0.2, i.e., if the sstable is more than 20% tombstones it will be considered for a tombstone compaction.  Tombstone compactions are only performed if no other compactions are queued.